# Would it make sense to run JavaScript on the Lua VM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-construction, lua

Lua is small and can be easily embedded. The current JavaScript VMs are quite big and hard to integrate into existing applications.
So wouldn't it be possible to compile JavaScript to Lua or Lua bytecode?
Especially for the constraints in mobile applications this seems like a good fit. Being able to easily integrate one of the most popular scripting languages into any iPhone or Android app would be great.

I'm not very familiar with Lua so I don't know if this is technically feasible.
With [Luvit](https://github.com/luvit/luvit) there is an active project trying to port the Node.js architecture to Lua. So the evented JavaScript world can't be too far away from whats possible in Lua.

Comment: Surely V8 can be (and is, by Node.js) used as a C library.

Comment: I updated my question - you are right V8 can be used as a library. But due to its complexity its not something a developer would do for a single app project. There are also constraints regarding native code generation on iOS.
Embedding Lua is far easier and quite common among games.

Comment: Just a comment regarding Node.js - `luvit` is not the only and not the first project to port Node.js to Lua, there is also [LuaNode](https://github.com/ignacio/LuaNode). It uses `boost.asio` instead of `libuv`.

Comment: You use JavaScript where you have to, such as in the browser, but if you have the option to use Lua, why would you choose to use JavaScript instead? Lua is simply a better language.

Comment: @Mud Maybe Lua really is the "better" language. But there are a lot of happy JavaScript users who might like to have a lightweight way of embedding js code into apps.

Comment: A generation of programmers suffered through TCL after better alternatives existed through of that kind of reasoning. :) I prefer technologies to be perpetuated on their merits, not on the momentum of their user base. Lua is like a sister to Javascript, tiny, simple, dynamic language using hashtables for data structuring and prototyping for inheritance. However, Lua is much cleaner and avoids all of JavaScript's annoying quirks (scoping, tail calls, etc.) and adds some incredibly powerful features (like metatables and coroutines) while *still* being smaller and faster.

Comment: My intention was not to start a Lua vs. JavaScript discussion. I'm simply interested in how technically feasible it is to compile JavaScript to Lua or Lua bytecode.

Comment: To be fair, your question is titled "*Would it make sense to* ...". That's the spirit I answered in. It's kinda a given that it's technically possible; you can compile any Turning complete language into another.

Answer (score 6):

The wins of compiling Javascript to Lua are not as great as you might first imagine. Javascript's semantics are very different to Lua's (the LuaJIT author cites Lua's design as one of the main reasons LuaJIT can compete so favourably with Javascript JIT compilers).

Take this code:

```
if("1" == 1)
{
    print("Yes");
}
```

This prints "Yes" in Javascript. The equivalent code in Lua does not, as strings are never equal to numbers in Lua. This may seem like a small point, but it has a fundamental consequence: we can no longer use Lua's built-in equality testing.

There are two solutions we could take. We could rewrite `1 == "1"` to `javascript_equals(1, "1")`. Or we could wrap every Javascript value in Lua, and use Lua's metatables to override the == operator behaviour.

So we already lost a some efficiency from Lua by mapping Javascript to it. This is a simple example, but it continues like this all the way down. For example all the operator rules are different between Javascript and Lua.

We would even have to wrap Javascript objects, because they aren't the same as Lua tables. For example Javascript objects only support string keys, and coerce any index to a string:

```
> a = {}
{}
> a[1] = "Hello"
'Hello'
> a["1"]
'Hello'
```

You also have to watch out for Javascript's scoping rules, vararg functions, and so on.

Now, all of these things are surmountable, if someone were to put the effort into a full compiler. However any efficiency gains would soon be drowned out. You would essentially end up building a Javascript interpreter in Lua. Most Javascript interpreters are written in C and already optimised for Javascript's semantics.

So, doing it for efficiency is a lost cause. There may be other reasons - such as supporting Javascript in a Lua-only environment, though even then if possible just writing Lua bindings to an existing Javascript interpreter would probably be less work.

If you want to have a play with a Javascript->Lua source-to-source translator, take a look at [js2lua](http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/js2lua/), which is a toy project I created some time back. It's not anywhere complete, but playing with it would certainly give some food for thought. It already includes a Javascript lexer, so that hard work is done already.